# Is there a way to get the vSphere Inventory Tree using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, vmware, vsphere

I've read lots of Ansible documentation on the modules and plugins for VMWare, but I still can't find a way to do what I think should be relatively simple. I'm looking to take a vCenter and extract the inventory tree, so I know all the datacenters in the vCenter, which clusters are in each datacenter and which VMs are in each cluster, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

I'm looking to gather and collate information about every VM on a vCenter, which I can almost do with the dynamic inventory plugin community.vmware.vmware_vm_inventory. However, none of the data it gathers about each VM seems to include the datacenter and cluster each VM is in.

Some of the VMWare modules require that you specify the datacenter or cluster a VM is in, so without this information, one cannot fully manage a vCenter. One would still need an external source of information in order to be able to convert a whole vCenter to a desired state.

Am I missing something? Is there some way to get the inventory tree structure that the vSphere web client provides, using the VMWare modules and plugins in Ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about use the vmware_vm_info module?
The vmware_vm_info can get the belonging information of each vm.

```yaml
---
- name: Example Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Gather all vm info
      vmware_vm_info:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: false
      register: gather_all_vm_info_result

    - debug:
        msg:
          - "VM Name{% raw %}:{% endraw %} {{ item.guest_name }}"
          - "Datacenter Name{% raw %}:{% endraw %} {{ item.datacenter }}"
          - "Cluster Name{% raw %}:{% endraw %}: {{ item.cluster }}"
          - "ESXi Name{% raw %}:{% endraw %} {{ item.esxi_hostname }}"
          - "Folder Name{% raw %}:{% endraw %} {{ item.folder }}"
      loop: "{{ gather_all_vm_info_result.virtual_machines }}"
```

**Output Example**

```
    "msg": [
        "VM Name: test_vm1",
        "Datacenter Name: DC",
        "Cluster Name:: Cluster",
        "ESXi Name: esxi-host.example.com",
        "Folder Name: /DC/vm"
    ]
```